# Python - reading last line only from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to login into devices using a text file with host IPs written like this:

**devlogin.txt**

```
192.168.201.1
192.168.201.2
192.168.201.1
```

Problem is Python only picks up last host on last line and ignores top lines
how can this be solve so, login works line by line for all hosts

```
with open('devlogin.txt','r')as HOSTS:
    for HOST in HOSTS:

cisco1 = {
           "host" : HOST,
           "username" : "***",
           "password": "***",
           "device_type" : "cisco_ios",
          }

net_connect = Netmiko(**cisco1)
```

Comment: This cannot be your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line like this:

```
with open('devlogin.txt','r') as HOSTS:

    HOSTS = HOSTS.read().split('\n')

    for HOST in HOSTS:

        ...
```